# Why form input of type text is disabled or read-only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to resolve a "browser compatibility" issue on our old website, which has a lot of javascript, css and html. they are asp pages, but I'm evaluating what actually is getting sent to the browser.

We have a page that has several text boxes (html input element of type=text) that you can't type into them unless you are on IE 7. Newer versions of IE and other modern browsers, when you click on the text box, you don't even get the flashing I beam cursor. But it momentarily flashes the border.

In Chrome, I right clicked and did Inspect Element, and I removed the text boxes class and all event handlers and the problem remained. Then I inspected the usual suspects: read-only, disabled, enabled, max-length, and they are all unrestricted.

What other DOM properties or style attributes can I check? Should I not assume that just because I removed html in Chrome inspect elements tab, it took effect?

I'm just looking for a list of weird things to check since I'm not primarily a web developer. The fact that it works in an older browser but no newer browsers makes me think that some html, css or javascript has come to be interpreted differently or additional things are being handled that were not handled before. Perhaps the newer browsers have uncovered (brought to the surface) some bad / illogical code.

EDIT:
Here is a fiddle that reproduces the problem, at least in Chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/2n2sJ/6/

```
<input type="text"/>



var ns6 = document.getElementById && !document.all
var isMenu = false;
var menuSelObj = null;
var overpopupmenu = false;

function mouseSelect(e) {
    var obj = ns6 ? e.target.parentNode : event.srcElement.parentElement;

    if (isMenu) {
        if (overpopupmenu == false) {
            isMenu = false;
            overpopupmenu = false;
            document.getElementById('menudiv').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = "none";
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

document.onmousedown = mouseSelect;
```

Comment: Read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 1) You did not do or have shown that you did your research. Did you Google for "HTML DOM properties" or "HTML style attributes" for a start?

Comment: I have no idea what is causing the problem, and the amount of code in the website means I can't include it here. So we can't ask for general guidance on things to check for on this site? I can't believe that's true. If I could put it in a neat tidy box, I'd have it solved. Getting the minimum code to repro the problem would be 95% of the solution!

Comment: @toddmo It is impossible to know what your problem is. Unless you can make a small demo with the problem, we will not be able to help.

Comment: @epascarello, I'm getting closer and closer to that in my jsfiddle. Can I get my downvotes back when I'm done?

Comment: Well that code says cancel the click if it is not the menu. I doubt that is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a click or focus event is handled by javascript, and the javascript returns false, this will make the text box appear to be disabled.

Have the handler return true instead of false to allow the event to occur.